# GitHub merging two different repos?

Tags: java, git, github

I have a Java program and I created one repo locally and pushed it to GitHub repo.

Then my friend has git and he cloned or downloaded these files from GitHub from same account of mine.

Now because of some issue, I was not able to push to GitHub. So I deleted `.git` file in my project and uninstalled git from my system and again installed it.

Again created my new repo in GitHub and again pushed it.
Now my friend did some changes in the program and committed it and pushed it to the old repo.

Now I want to merge his repo with my new repo.
Since all the files are the same, just some code has changed, so how to do it?

Comment: to make that clear: how many *github* repositories exist(ed) over all?

Comment: Have you done any prior research?

Answer (score 1):

If the history is not that important, you can import the old repo, merge, and push.

```
cd /path/to/new/local/repo
git remote add oldrepo https://github.com/<user>/<oldrepo>
git fetch oldrepo


git checkout master
git merge oldrepo/master

git push
```